# Is there a way to call modeless form in pages using cakephp3

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, modeless

as what I read online it will only be available for like this 
http://localhost/xxxxx/contact then the form will display

but I want it to display in many pages like contact us, or about us page

when i call this pages I want the form appear in the content?

Template

**index.ctp**

```
<?= $this->Form->create($contact); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('name'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('email'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('body'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Submit'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**ContactController.php**

```
<?php
// In a controller
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use App\Form\ContactForm;

class ContactController extends AppController
{
public function index()
{
$contact = new ContactForm();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
if ($contact->execute($this->request->data)) {
$this->Flash->success('Your message has been sent; we\'ll get back to you soon!');
$this->request->data['name'] = null;
$this->request->data['email'] = null;
$this->request->data['body'] = null;
} else {
$this->Flash->error('There was a problem submitting your form.');
}
}
$this->set('contact', $contact);
}
}

?>
```

**ContactForm.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;

use Cake\Form\Form;
use Cake\Form\Schema;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\Mailer\Email;

class ContactForm extends Form
{

protected function _buildSchema(Schema $schema)
{
return $schema->addField('name', 'string')
->addField('email', ['type' => 'string'])
->addField('body', ['type' => 'text']);
}

protected function _buildValidator(Validator $validator)
{
return $validator->add('name', 'length', [
'rule' => ['minLength', 10],
'message' => 'Please enter your name'
])->add('email', 'format', [
'rule' => 'email',
'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
])->add('body', 'length', [
'rule' => ['minLength', 25],
'message' => 'Please enter your message text',
]);
}

protected function _execute(array $data)
{
// Send an email.
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to get much more familiar with CakePHP and its Views and Controller concepts to be able to solve this as the solution is pretty much in what you posted already. You have all the pieces you just need to assemble them right.

Comment: why is it the  $this->set('contact', $contact); is not available in the element? view   "Undefined variable: contact"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fixed it by moving the contact template form into the element so that it will be available in any pages.

inside element in the contact folder, form below must be present

```
<legend><?= __('Our Form') ?></legend>
    <fieldset>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('body');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

then in your pages

you can just call

```
<?php 
   echo $this->element('contact/index');
 ?>
```

*assuming you created index.ctp inside contact folder in element*

Hope it solved your problem.

Comment: why is it the $this->set('contact', $contact); is not available in the element? view "Undefined variable: contact"